# Rotate image before uploading to server using php

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have build an iPhone app that uploads images to my server, it works fine but images captured from my iPhone cam is being rotated when uploaded

i searched for it and i found this code for fix the problem

```
-(UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image { // here we rotate the image in its orignel
int kMaxResolution = 640; // Or whatever

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = roundf(bounds.size.width / ratio);
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = roundf(bounds.size.height * ratio);
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
}
```

but i don't know how to use it

can you please help me ?

the uploading action is

```
- (IBAction)pushUpload {

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.domain.com/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSRange rangeValue = [returnString rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (rangeValue.length > 0){

        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
    }

 }
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but where here does PHP come into play??

Comment: i`m using php to upload the image

Comment: Ah, the title makes it seem like you want to "Rotate image ... using php"

Comment: @ZachL Thats why i wrote in the title before uploading, and the tags are all for iOS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
- (IBAction)pushUpload {

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:imageview.image], 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.domain.com/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSRange rangeValue = [returnString rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (rangeValue.length > 0){

        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
    }
 }
```